# Raspberry Pi Sense HAT on Rpi 3?

Tags: pi-3, hat, sense-hat

I have a question to ask you guys. Can I use the Raspberry Pi Sense HAT (the one used in Astro Pi) with the Raspberry Pi 3 without having any kind of problems?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hello and welcome. Please refrain from changing the title to *Solved: ...* that's not how things are done here. And please do not try to use the pi-foundation tag for your question. (see there: *This tag is to be used for questions relating to the Raspberry Pi Foundation, the Raspberry Pi website or the origins of the Raspberry Pi. **Do not** use this tag just because it is something to do with the Raspberry Pi.*)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 3 has the same form factor as the 2/0/+ models, with the same 40 pin GPIO header, so yes.  The buses involved will work the same way, hence so should the software.

Answer (score 1):

No it wont work the sense.hat temperature sensors are 6mm away from the CPU which has a temperature of 39 deg c. if you buy a sense hat board connect it remote from the board